# Django Find custom user with the same value of JSONfield

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-custom-user

I have a django application, where I use custom user model. Model has a JSONfield, which represents which programming languages do this user use.
It looks like this:

`{"langs": [1, 2, 3, 4]}`

These numbers are ID's of Language DB model.

So is it possible to find users in DB, who have 1 or more same language as the current user. I want to get an array with custom user objects sorted by number of matching langs.

Sorry if this question is too stupid.

Comment: I would really advise *not* to work with a `JsonField` to refer to other models. Typically a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) is used. This will be represented in a way on the database that makes it more convenient to filter, aggregate, etc. since Relational databases (SQL-like) are typically not good with dynamic and recursive data like JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise *not* to work with a `JsonField` to refer to other models. SQL databases often are not good with *recursive* and *dynamic* data, since that is not how a relational database conceptually is designed.

Typically a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) is used. This will work with a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/junction_table), which makes it more accessible and it can guarantee *referential integrity*.

We thus can model this with:

```
class ProgrammingLanguage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class User(models.Model):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProgrammingLanguage,
        related_name='users'
    )
```

If we then have a `User` object *`user`*, we can find users which have at least one language in common with:

```
User.objects.filter(
    languages__users=user
).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will avoid retrieving the *same* user that many times as they have languages in common.